# Ubuntu crashes within <1min of startup (new machine, both try and install options)

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, freeze

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my new computer (currently windows 10) and have followed the steps from https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows and https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop (in summary downloaded the iso, wrote it to a usb with rufus then restarted computer).

It seems to work fine for the first 20 or so seconds and then freezes and the fan becomes really loud. A few minutes later it brings up a screen with some messages stemming from "A start job is running for holds snappy daemon refresh (22s/no limit)". 
This was the end result after it stopped making any more messages - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEo1q.jpg

This happens in both cases that I choose try without installing and install ubuntu options, and I don't really know what to do to debug/fix from here.

Yes I've tried turning it off and on again.

Maybe useful info:

- Trying to install 18.04.3 LTS desktop
- Computer ASUS TUF Gaming FX705
- Processor 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7

Comment: Did you disable secure boot ?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Many systems need that, even if not installing Ubuntu,  for mitigation of Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities. Both Linux kernel, drivers & Windows have updates for those issues. But UEFI also needs updates.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and the steps [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349782&p=13596969#post13596969) solved my issue  (basically adjusting some flags, then installing Nvidia drivers).

1. Disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot.
2. Plug in the bootable Ubuntu live USB.
3. When you see the option to *Install Ubuntu* etc. press `e` and edit a line. Replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot. Reboot after the installation is complete.
4. This time you will now see the GRUB boot menu. Again press `e` and edit a line. In the line that starts with `linux` add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of that line.
5. After this, you need to install the Nvidia graphics driver and reboot with `sudo reboot`